# Basic mathematics in PHP Simplexml

Tags: php, simplexml

The code below is in PHP and returns prices from a XML response file.

```
$price = $result->Items->Item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->FormattedPrice; //lowest new price 
$listPrice = $result->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->FormattedPrice; //list price
```

If I echo $price or $listPrice it works

I wish to get the difference between the two prices but I am getting NULL if I do

```
$savings = $listPrice - $price; or $savings = ($listPrice - $price);
```

Any assistance is welcome

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely trying to subtract a string from a string.  You need to convert the values to a numeric type.  If you're working with prices, you'll probably want floating point numbers:

```
$price = floatval($result->Items->Item->OfferSummary->LowestNewPrice->FormattedPrice); //lowest new price 
$listPrice = floatval($result->Items->Item->Offers->Offer->OfferListing->Price->FormattedPrice); //list price

$savings = $listPrice - $price;
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume $price and $listprice are numbers (integers or doubles), so it is possible they appear to be numbers when echoing them alone, but they could be strings with whitespace that is preventing them from being parsed. Try using trim() to remove whitespace (eg, $price = trim($price)).

Comment: you can test if $price and $listPrice are numbers by using is_numeric()

Comment: `is_numeric` is almost never the function you want, as it accepts things like `1.5e10` (scientific notation). Admittedly, it might be appropriate here depending on the input, but people often use it when they should be using `ctype_digit` (which checks that a string consists entirely of digits).

Answer (score 0):

While they may appear to be numbers, it may be worth it to cast them to floats, just to make sure.

```
$savings = floatval($listPrice) - floatval($price);
```